# Can't create cores on solr 5.2.x due to access rights

Tags: ubuntu, tomcat, solr

I have installed solr 5.2.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Java 8.0_51

Somehow the system does not let me create cores. Not through the webmin interface and not through CLI.

It seems to be an access right problem. I therefore created the data and conf directory and changed owner to solr:solr. Copied the basic conf examples to the conf directory.

Now the core is created, but the web interface shows this error:

```
SolrCore Initialization Failures
test: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core test: Error loading solr config from /var/solr/data/test/conf/solrconfig.xml
new_core: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load conf for core new_core: Error loading solr config from /var/solr/data/new_core/conf/solrconfig.xml
```

This are the rights set:

```
merlin@rabbit:/var/solr/data$ l -l /var/solr/data/test/conf/
total 80
-rw-r--r-- 1 solr solr    33 May 28 18:10 _rest_managed.json
-rw-r--r-- 1 solr solr  3974 May 28 18:10 currency.xml
drwxr-xr-x 2 solr solr  4096 Aug  7 10:34 lang/
-rw-r--r-- 1 solr solr   873 May 28 18:10 protwords.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 solr solr 29206 May 28 18:10 schema.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 solr solr 22555 Jun 10 16:02 solrconfig.xml
-rw-r--r-- 1 solr solr   781 May 28 18:10 stopwords.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 solr solr  1119 May 28 18:10 synonyms.txt
```

Looks all good to me and this is a standard installation. Does somebody have an idea how to fix this? Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: found a "somehow" fix on serverfault: "I created a directory for my core in the Solr Home folder and within it added a folder called conf. To this folder, I copied all the files which were there in the conf folder of the other core and after that ran the CREATE command. Booyah ! It worked." worked for me too, but seems very odd procedure.

Comment: I had the same issue with only the "new_core" line. This was after several unsuccessful clicks of the "Add Core" button, and once I finally got my configs in the right place, I was able to create my core (by a different name). That one showed up fine, but the error appeared regarding "new_core". I did `sudo service solr restart` and the message went away.